# Remove extra charactors from xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following sample xml input.

```
<inputM xmlns="http://example.com">
<Title>test</Title>
<Gender>ffff</Gender>
<MiddleName>dere</MiddleName>
<Surname>qqq</Surname>
<PreferredName>ppp</PreferredName>
</inputM>
```

Based on logic, I want to generate a JSON message. For that I used below xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns="http://example.com" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="application/json"/>
    <xsl:template match="ns:inputM">
        <xsl:text>{"outputX": {</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:Title,'xxx','title')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:Gender,'yyy','gender')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:MiddleName,'zzz','middleName')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:Surname,'qqq','surname')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:PreferredName,'ppp','preferredName')" />
        <xsl:text>}}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:function name="ns:getChangedValue">
        <xsl:param name="inputValue"/>
        <xsl:param name="default"/>
        <xsl:param name="jsonField"/>
            <xsl:if test="$inputValue != $default">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$inputValue = 'TEST'" >
                    <func:result>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',$jsonField,'&quot;: &quot; removed')" />
                        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        </func:result>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <func:result>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',$jsonField,'&quot;: &quot;', $inputValue)" />
                        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        </func:result>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The generated output is like below.

```
{"outputX": {"title": "test","gender": "ffff","middleName": "dere",}}
```

There is always extra "," after the last element in the output message. Is there a way to avoid this from a single xslt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting the comma in your function, but obviously the function does not know if there is a following value that will appear or not.

One way to solve it, would be to change the function so it didn't add the comma, and have all the function calls done with a single `xsl:value-of` with a `separator`.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:ns="http://example.com" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="application/json"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns:inputM">
        <xsl:text>{"outputX": {</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:Title,'xxx','title'), 
                              ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:Gender,'yyy','gender'),
                              ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:MiddleName,'zzz','middleName'),
                              ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:Surname,'qqq','surname'),
                              ns:getChangedValue(//ns:inputM/ns:PreferredName,'ppp','preferredName')" separator=", " />
        <xsl:text>}}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="ns:getChangedValue">
        <xsl:param name="inputValue"/>
        <xsl:param name="default"/>
        <xsl:param name="jsonField"/>
        <xsl:if test="$inputValue != $default">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$inputValue = 'TEST'" >
                <func:result>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',$jsonField,'&quot;: &quot; removed')" />
                    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    </func:result>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <func:result>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',$jsonField,'&quot;: &quot;', $inputValue)" />
                    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    </func:result>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note you should really change the version number of the XSLT to "2.0".